# Increasing the number of nonzero digits (from AOPS)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found this currently unsolved problem in the AOPS site ([link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1686165)):

> Let $n$ be a positive integer with exactly $d$ non-zero digits. Show that there is a multiple of $n$ which has exactly $d+1$ non-zero digits.

It seems to be quite challenging and I have no idea how to solve it. Any hints how to proceed?

Comment: Interesting problem! Could be out of reach.

Comment: How many digits does $n$ have? Is it $d$ or more?

Comment: @user582949 $n$ can have more than $d$ digits: $d$ are nonzero and the others are zero.

Answer (score 5):

You can combine three simple tricks to solve the problem:

1. Take a digit greater than $1$, and split it into two nonzero digits by adding $10^t-10^s$.
2. If each digit in your number $n$ is $0$ or $1$, replace $n$ by $2n$.
3. In order to get rid of the prime factors $2$ and $5$, multiply $n$ by a power of $10$.

---

If $n$ has a digit greater than $1$ then let $m=n$. Otherwise, if each digit of $n$ are $0$ or $1$ then let $m=2n$. Hence $m$ is a multiple of $n$, it has the same nonzero digits as $n$, and $m$ has at least one digit grater than $1$.

Let $m=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_i\cdot 10^i$ where $a_0,\ldots,a_{k-1}$ are the decimal digits of $m$ and let $g$ be an index with $a_g\ge2$.

Take two integers $t,s$ such that $s>g$, $t>s+k$ and $10^t\equiv 10^s\pmod{n}$, and choose
$$
M = 10^{s-g}m + (10^t-10^s).
$$
The factor $10^{s-g}$ shifts the digit $a_g$ to the $s$th position.
The term $10^t-10^s$ replaces the digit $a_g$ by $a_g-1$ (which is nonzero), and adds a new leading digit $1$. Due to $t-s>k$, this leading $1$ is not added to the previous nonzero digits.

Comment: I have a few questions, but perhaps the most significant is this: Is there a guarantee that we can always choose such $s,t$ so that $10^s\equiv 10^t \pmod n$?

Comment: @Allawonder By the pigeonhole principle, in the infinite sequence $\{10^n\}_n$  there are infinite couples $(10^s,10^t)$ with $s\not=t$ such that $10^s$ and $10^t$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$.

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks for your response, but I cannot say I understand your argument. Could you be more explicit as to how the pigeonhole principle does what we want? On the other hand the number $10^s-10^t$ is always of the form $\underbrace{999...99}_{s-t \,\,\,9's}\underbrace{00...0}_{t\,\,\, 0's}.$ How does this help us out? I mean, apart from the fact that it is not obvious that every prime divides a number of this form, how does it help to increase the digit by just one in every case? I don't know if I'm making any sense.

Comment: @Allawonder Note that $M = 10^t +10^{s-g}m -10^s$: $10^t$ increases the number of non-zero digits and $10^{s-g}m -10^s$ decreases by one the digit at $s$-position (which is at least $2$).

Comment: @RobertZ I think I'm beginning to get the gist now. I pay attention to notation, and the parentheses around $10^t-10^s$ may have misled me into thinking of it as $10^s(10^{t-s}-1).$

Comment: @RobertZ Thank you very much. I think I now understand the proof (albeit its language is misleadingly constructive), although I have one last question, if you will. Out of the three simple tricks mentioned by the author in the preface, only the first two seen to have been used; I don't see where or how #3 was used. Of course, $m$ is scaled by $10^{s-g},$ but that is just to change the position of $a_g$ and has nothing explicitly to do with the prime factors of $10.$ Say what is the significance of trick #3 -- I ask this in case I may be missing something. PS. Although I later understood why...

Comment: ...$10^t-10^s$ is a multiple of every $n$ not coprime to $10$ by Euler's theorem, I'm still curious as to your mentioning of the pigeonhole principle. If you will please explain what it does here -- I like to understand a proof from multiple perspectives, especially when it seems like I might be missing an important one which can be used elsewhere. Thanks.